# Show nested folders in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

I know that default "CTRL+B" Windows command works for showing all nested files.

Is there a shortcut to show all nested folders?

Comment: Here are all the shortcuts of Total Commander, I hope you may find what  you are searching for https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Total-Commander_8.html

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if this feature exists in Total Commander. The built-in `tree` utility is always good enough for me.

If you don't like console output, just run this inside Total Commander's command line to copy the output to the clipboard:

```
tree | clip
```

Of course, you can assign it a shortcut. :)

Answer (score 0):

Total Commander by version differs from the oldest one, if u can't find ur desired shortcut, just simply set this shortcut on the configuration panel as following:

```
>Start 
   >Change main menu
      >Configuration
        >Misc.
          >Redefine Hotkeys...
```